# Javascript Classname Click without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert this code below to vanilla javascript because we cannot use jQuery

```
if (isSafari) {
   $('.buttonClassName').click(function() {
    // do something
});
}
```

I was trying something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
if (isSafari) {
 document.getElementByClassName("buttonClassName").onclick = function () {
  // do something
};
}
```

What javascript can I use without jQuery

Comment: its getElementsByClassName, not getElementByClassName

Comment: Reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) is always useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonClassName');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    element.onclick = function() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it useful to build an array of my query selection so I can use Array prototype functions on the element collection. This selector function will be useful if you can't use jQuery:

```
function elem (selector) {
  return Array.apply(this, document.querySelectorAll(selector));
}

elem('.buttonClassName').forEach(function (el) {
  el.onclick = fn;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

### use getElementsByClassName

```
document.getElementsByClassName('buttonClassName')[0].onclick = myFunc;
```

**See demo:** http://jsbin.com/nihovadoto/edit?html,js,output

Comment: This makes a bold assumption that a class name is being used only once. Chances are, it isn't. If it were, they'd be using an ID.

Comment: Agree, however, I wanted to highlight the typo in the given code and that  getElementsByClassName returns array.

Answer (score -1):

Everything looks close . I suggest caching your button(s) and trying an event listener like below

Example

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonClassName');

buttons.addEventListener('click' , doSomething);
```

Hope this helps